# R Piecewise Function Plotting

Tags: r, plot, smoothing, piecewise

So I read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329285/r-plot-piecewise-function) and then went ahead to define a piecewise function using `ifelse`.

I have a piecewise function defined to illustrate the penalty dollar amount `p` of not insuring to value at different loss amounts of `x` dollars.

```
p <- function(x){
  return(ifelse(x <=300, x - x*(300/400) , 
      ifelse(x > 300 & x <= 400,  300 - x*(300/400),
      ifelse(x > 400, 0, 0))))}
plot(p(0:500),type="l")
```

As you can see the output is not really very smooth, my question:

1. any plot option to make it perfectly smooth (as it should be here)?
2. how to plot only within the `x` ranging from `200` to `420`, a plot point every `10` loss dollar increment? I suppose this maybe something really simple that I am not aware `200:10:420` ??

Comment: Not sure I follow both parts of the question, but for #2, try playing with `seq(from = 200, to = 420, by = 10)`

Comment: What do you mean "perfectly smooth"? The plot is exactly as you have defined it: for x<300, p=0.75x, for x in (300,400), p=300 - 0.75x, and for x>400, p=0.